# Spring Webflux + LDAP/Kerberos Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-webflux, spring-security-kerberos

I got a Spring Boot 2 Reactive Web Application that currently has a JWT-based authentication system. Now I would like to add a LDAP backend for authentication and allow Single-Sign On (SSO) via Kerberos.
It seems Kerberos and LDAP support is currently limited to webmvc and no dedicated reactive version is available.
Since documentation about integrating all 3 components (WebFlux, LDAP + Kerberos) together in one application is quiet rare *I would like to ask if someone of you already took the attempt to set-up such an infrastructure and is willing to share an example how to do.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issues with SAML. I haven't seen any progress on porting these sub projects to be supported in a webflux environment. The obvious approach seems to me to rewrite all servlet filters to WebFilters.